# Синхронизация локальных java-проектов с сервером

Tags: java, git, netbeans

Делал как-то веб-проект на php в netbeans и там можно было настроить так проект, чтобы при сохранении все изменения выгружались на сервер и так же быстро можно было загрузить чужой проект к себе на машину. Сейчас пишу приложения на java и этого очень не хватает, т.к. нужен оперативный доступ к проектам.

Первым делом начал копать в сторону git. Создал локальный и серверный репозитории. Вношу изменения в локальный репозиторий и выгружаю на сервер. После этого в серверном репозитории появляется информация по поводу модифицированных файлов, но ни слова о новых, а мне это как раз и нужно.

Можно ли как-то выгружать java-проекты на сервер через netbeans? Или может нужно действовать как-то иначе?